# Reverse String Function in Python (Primitive Steps)

Tags: python

I tried coming up with a way to do a reverse string function without using the [ : : -1] method. I'm new to coding and am trying to only use the "primitive" steps. Below is my function and specifications. I was wondering if this is an efficient way to write the function. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
def reverse(word):
    x = -2                     #word in reversed order counter
    y = 1                      #starts counter to end "while" statement below
    reversed = word[-1]        #starts the reversed-word at last letter of word
    while len(word) > y:       #ending parameter for when all letters run through loop
        reversed += word[x]    #adds letters to reversed word starting at word[-2]
        x -= 1                 #moves position in word 1 to the left
        y += 1                 #increases the counter by 1
return reversed
```

Comment: No, it’s seriously inefficient, but there’s no reason to write your own in the real word regardless, so…

Comment: Appending to a string n times will typically take O(n²) time, unless the string implementation performs the appropriate overallocation (Python's string type doesn't). So no, this isn't anywhere near efficient.

Comment: a better place to ask this would be codereview.stackoverflow.com

Comment: What do you mean by *primitive steps*? As you say, there's 101 variations of doing this on SO. Your code would only end up going towards one of those... I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect to this question...

Comment: I started the MIT computer science courses offered on youtube and the professor describes "primitive" as only those pieces of code that are necessary to have a Turing complete language. So I suppose variables, operators and conditionals. But thank you for pointing me to the codereview forum of stackoverflow. The question should have been posted there. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to a string is slow. It's probably best to make a list of the characters in the string in reversed order, then use the string method `join` on it.

Example code (fairly close to your original function):

```
def reverse(word):
    index = len(word)-1                  
    result = []      
    while index >= 0: 
        result.append(word[index]) 
        index -= 1 
    return "".join(result)
```

Better example code:

```
def reverse(word):
    word_list = []
    for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1):
        word_list.append(word[i])
    return "".join(word_list)

def reverse(word):
    return "".join(word[i] for i in range(len(word)-1, -1, -1))
```

Even better code:

```
def reverse(word):
    return "".join(reversed("abc"))
```

or

```
def reverse(word):
    return word[::-1]
```

But of course, the most efficient code is that with the fewest characters. [/sarcasm]

```
reverse =lambda s:s and s[-1]+reverse(s[:-1])or s
```

Yet another solution (I think it is likely to be slow):

```
def reverse(word):
    word_list = []
    for i in word:
        word_list.insert(0, word[i])
    return "".join(word_list)
```

Comment: @jeremynealbrown: Read the first sentence of the question.

Comment: why not `for c in word: word_list.append(c) ...`?

Comment: Thanks. I was messing around with the idea of using append but then I realized that it doesn't work for a string. Didn't even know about the join method.

Comment: "Adding to a string is slow." This was optimized some time ago and is probably not as slow as you think. If the string has only one reference, as it would in this case, it's modified in place rather than being copied upon each concatenation.

Comment: @kindall How is it modified in place? I thought strings were immutable.

Comment: Strings are immutable *to the Python program.* But they are stored in memory and that memory isn't write-protected or anything. The Python interpreter itself is free to modify a string in-place since it has direct access to the memory, and it is safe to do so when there is only one reference to the string. (And Python already knows how many references there are, since it tracks this for every object.)

Comment: @kindall Thanks for informing me. So does the same thing not apply if you have multiple variables referring to the string? And does this mean there is no speed disadvantage in doing, say, `functools.reduce(operator.add, list_of_strings)` rather than `"".join(list_of_strings)`?

Comment: Hard to say the speed differences without using `timeit` but yeah, having more than one variable pointing to a string disables this optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I like the functional-ish recursive way, but this may not be the best for Python:

```
def rev(w): 
    return rev(w[1:]) + w[0] if w else w
```

You'd want to include type checking or something, or possibly extend this a bit to handle any iterable and not just a string.

Comment: No, this is good. If you extended it a bit to handle every iterable, you’d have `reversed` :)